# qcow2 Disk size much bigger than virtual size

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qcow2

What would cause this? `ls` shows the qcow2 to be 241G, in the VM it only has ~ 160 GB drive, no unpartitioned space.  Win 7 VM, Host = EXT4 2.6 Kernel virsh 0.9.10

`file format: qcow2
virtual size: 160G (171798692352 bytes)
disk size: 241G
cluster_size: 65536
Snapshot list:
ID        TAG                 VM SIZE                DATE       VM CLOCK
1         1373999350             1.9G 2013-07-16 14:29:10 1321:53:10.348`

Comment: snapshots in use?

Comment: Doesn't the output I posted show that the snapshot is only taking 1.9G?

Comment: Not necessarily. Are there additional snapshot files there?

Comment: How else can I tell besides qemu-img info/snapshot -l virsh snapshot-list?  All of these point to just one snapshot

Comment: `qemu-img info` will not display the netire snapshot chain, but only the previous snapshot, unless you're running some weird version. Look at http://kashyapc.wordpress.com/2012/09/14/externaland-live-snapshots-with-libvirt/